# How to match CatBoost GPU metrics to CPU metrics?

Tags: precision, auc, precision-recall, catboost

I have been using CatBoost on CPU and got good results, but wanted to speed it up by using GPU. However, all metrics from GPU are worse than those from CPU. I did search around and found a suggestion that one could try to increase border_count to 255. I tried that but it did not help.

Some have claimed that GPU output would yield variations. While it might be true, I have found these variations are always worse than the CPU metrics.

Any pointer that I can try? It is a binary classification project. It has 1.2M rows for training and 120K rows for validattion. It has 218 features and 42 of them are categorical. The rest are floats or integers.